# Magento : The PayPal Gateway rejected the request. The transaction has already been Accepted / Denied and the status can not be changed (# 11614: )

Tags: php, magento, paypal

[image]I can able to place an order via paypal but when I am going to accept accept payment I am getting the following error.

```html
The PayPal Gateway rejected the request. The transaction has already been Accepted / Denied and the status can not be changed (# 11614: The transaction has already been Accepted / Denied and the status can not be changed).
```

[image]Is there any one who can help me with this.

Comment: What is the status within Paypal? Has the order already been affected there?

Comment: You mean In my seller account or buyer account ?

Comment: I would assume seller account as this is what would be accepting/declining.

Comment: I checked it in seller account status say "Not booked" what I need to check next

Comment: @DouglasRadburn I have just upload paypal images